# Zurb Foundation show modal after validation

Tags: jquery, meteor, zurb-foundation

I'm using Foundation in my project. When the form is submitted, modal is opened with some message. I want to open modal if validation is ok. How to achieve this? I've tried adding attributes data-reveal etc. but nothing is happening.

Comment: you're not new to SO, you know that without code it will be difficult for others to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the modales use this awesome package [peppelg:bootstrap-3-modal](https://atmospherejs.com/peppelg/bootstrap-3-modal).

**HTML**

```
<template name="exampleModal">
<!-- Modal Stuff -->
</template>
```

So this is how our validation will look

**JS**

```
Template.example.rendered = function(){
$('#myForm')
      .on('invalid.fndtn.abide', function () {
        var invalid_fields = $(this).find('[data-invalid]');
        console.log(invalid_fields);
      })
      .on('valid.fndtn.abide', function () {
            Modal.show('exampleModal') //on valid we show the modal super easy
      });
}
```